# Laravel Cashier returning false on newly created subscription

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a new subscription with Laravel 5.4 and cashier 7.0, but after creating the subscription I am trying to return some values from the `Billable` trait, but they return false. For example:

```
public function persist(Company $company)
{
    $company->newSubscription('default', $this->input('plan'))->create($this->input('token'));

    return response()->json([
        'subscribed' => $company->subscribed(),
        'onTrial'    => $company->onTrial()
    ]);
}
```

Both `'subscribed'` and `'onTrial'` are false even though the model got subscribed and both properties should return true. How do I access cashier methods on a controller immediately after the subscription was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
public function persist(Company $company)
{
  $subscription = $company->newSubscription('default', $this->input('plan'))->create($this->input('token'));

  return $subscription->owner()->subscribed(); //returns true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today while trying to assert the user was subscribed to a plan.

The solution was to refresh the user model after creating the subscription but before calling subscribed:

```
$this->user->refresh();
```

The problem happens because Laravel Cashier preloads the subscriptions relationship in the user model before creating the new subscription.

So you can also reload the subscriptions with:

```
$this->user->load('subscriptions');
```

Before calling `subscribed` and that should do the trick as well.